# create multiple next and previous button in jquery on single page with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in JavaScript and Jquery and I am facing problem while creating a code for multiple drop-down with next and previous option , but I don't want to write twice same code for next and previous. I just wanted to use same code dynamically. I have tried but did not got any answer. Plzz suggest ....

```
<div class="filter-category">
    <div class="floor-dropdown"> 
        <span class="prev">Prev</span>
        <select class="roof-filter">
            <option value="1" selected>All types</option>
            <option value="2">Type1</option>
            <option value="3">Type 2</option>
        </select> 
        <span class="next">Next</span>
    </div>
    <div class="floor-dropdown"> 
        <span class="prev">Prev</span>
        <select class="roof-filter">
            <option>011</option>
            <option>222</option>
            <option>333</option>
            <option>444</option>
        </select> 
        <span class="next">Next</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
jQuery(".roof-prev").click(function () {
    jQuery('.roof-filter option:selected').prev().attr('selected', 'selected');
});
jQuery(".roof-next").click(function () {
    jQuery('.roof-filter option:selected').next().attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Please don't write this code with different class name for second one, I want to use this code without writing again.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `this` as a reference to the element which was clicked. From that you can find the `select` it relates to by finding the closest common parent. Try this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".prev").click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.floor-dropdown').find('option:selected').prev().attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
    $(".next").click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.floor-dropdown').find('option:selected').next().attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/q9h0rb0s/)

Comment: Thank Rory  for your reply..... This code is working fine but when first time I clicked for next/prev its working fine but for second time both are not working ... I don't know the exact reason.